# Django REST Framework - how to do Token Authentication with Memcached

Tags: django, memcached, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-cache

I am using TokenAuthentication for several of my DRF views. The view code itself have optimized logic for to use memcached if the key exists in the cache - to speed up by reducing DB queries. However, I see that for each of the API requests from phone(client), the server still does one query at least - `Postgres authtoken_token select` for validating user for the authtoken sent

Is there a way to avoid this, since the authtoken is rarely changed - by keeping it in the cache?

I am using the following in `settings.py`, but I don't think this is helping my case

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db"
```

Comment: Cannot find any code utilizing cache for token auth in DRF 3.3.1. Simply a model filter query for every request...

Answer (score 0):

- You can set TIMEOUT to None while setting token in memcache, such that cached token will never expire (untill memcache server restart/eviction). Or you can set long duration for timeout to minimize the DB queries.
- Alternatively you can opt for Redis with [django-redis](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache) as you caching backend. [Redis](https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache) provides persistant cache option.